# IBM iSeries AS400 VBscript macro loop not exiting despite exit condition being met

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I have created a macro in VBA for our IBM iSeries / AS400 / green screen environment which finds item numbers within purchase orders and then changes their price and exits out of the purchase order. Within the macro is a loop used to parse through each line of the purchase order and then pagedown to the next page of lines if the number is not found on the first page. Here is the code for the loop:

```
'ItemNum and Price are entered by the user within Excel
Do Until IBMItemNum = ItemNum
    If NumRow = 11 Then
        'There are ten lines within purchase orders, after which one must page down
        'to see the rest of the purchase order. This is where the problem occurs
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pagedn]"
        NumRow = 1
    End If
    IBMItemNum = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(NumRow, 2, 5)
    If IBMItemNum = ItemNum Then
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos NumRow, 66
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys Price
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[field+]"
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
        'After the item has been found and the price entered, the macro exits the PO
        'Entering PageDown after the PO has been exited crashes the AS400 session
        Exit Do
    Else
        'Check the next row
        NumRow = NumRow + 1
    End If
Loop
```

This macro can successfully read every number on the first page of the purchase order in succession, if and only if I remove the PageDown SendKeys command from the loop. However, even if the ItemNum is the first IBMItemNum on the PO, the macro will not exit the loop and will page down (which also means the loop has reiterated 10+ times). Is my code missing something for the exit condition?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the `If IBMItemNum = ItemNum then` line and checked the values of both where you expect them to match?  If you're pulling 5 chars in you might be grabbing empty space causing a mismatch, or lower case isn't matching upper case etc.

Comment: The items are matching, and I also changed the third parameter in gettext to a variable ItemNumLen = Len(ItemNum) so I always pull the right amount of characters. The macro functions perfectly as long as I stay on the first page. When I add the pagedown, that's when it crashes, even with the sleep time

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a delay  after `autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"`.  This will give the screen time to update.

Sleep API is ideal `Sleep 250` will stop your code for 500 milliseconds (1/2 of a second).

> ```
> Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
> ```

The easiest fix is to use a large delay.  Alternately, you could use a smaller delays and use `GetText` to see if the screen has updated.

```
'ItemNum and Price are entered by the user within Excel
Do
    If NumRow = 11 Then
        'There are ten lines within purchase orders, after which one must page down
        'to see the rest of the purchase order. This is where the problem occurs
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pagedn]"
        NumRow = 1
    End If
    IBMItemNum = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(NumRow, 2, 5)
    If IBMItemNum = ItemNum Then
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos NumRow, 66
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys Price
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[field+]"
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
        Sleep 500
        'After the item has been found and the price entered, the macro exits the PO
        'Entering PageDown after the PO has been exited crashes the AS400 session
        Exit Do 'Not needed
    Else
        'Check the next row
        NumRow = NumRow + 1
    End If
    DoEvents

Loop Until IBMItemNum = ItemNum
```

Comment: @Mike good call.  I was wondering if they had a built in method.  I've never worked with AS400 API.